# Which tile completes the set?

Tags: pattern, geometry, visual

[image: Puzzle]

This one puzzles me. I hope you can solve it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the answers is

> A

Since

> The first three (C, D, L) are an English letter and it's horizontal reflection.

From the options

> Only A is an combination of an English letter and it's reflection (E)

Comment: Got there just before I could. +1.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> B

Because

> The top left contains the letter C reflected upon itself, and the top right contains the subsequent letter, D, reflected upon itself. The bottom left contains the letter T upside-down, and tile B contains the subsequent letter, U, upside-down.

My first choice of answer wasn't here. If there had been a tile containing

> the letter M reflected upon itself

I would have chosen that, because

> the bottom left tile could also be read as the letter L reflected upon itself.

Comment: Note that the puzzle is to complete the "set", not the "sequence". There's no reason to think that the correct answer follows on from the bottom-left tile. It's just a case of finding the operation common to all 3 tiles.

Comment: Ooh, good point. In which case I really was looking for the MM.

Comment: I'd say this would be my answer also, since there is a letter T upside-down. Where people see reflected L? reflected L would be 1,5 times wider that T.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought about this possibility, though I can fully understand your reasoning.